# Fetch all Names in Option Value, but getting only 1

Tags: reactjs, mongoose

I am getting array of objects on props.items. How to show all the name from props.items.name in option select? What is happening now is : I am only fetching Name for selected user but not getting all the users and select any choice. I am new to reactjs. Can anyone help me out yrr. Thanks in advance.

[image]

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Container, Row, Col, Form, Modal } from 'react-bootstrap';
import configData from './../../config/constant.json'
const TransferDialog = (props) => {
  let [transferDiv, showtransferDiv] = useState(false)
  let [deleteDiv, showDeleteDiv] = useState(false)
  let [confirmDiv, showConfirmDiv] = useState(true);
  let [error, setError] = useState(false);
  let [pending, setPending] = useState(false);
  let [permission, setPermission] = useState();
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState([])
  const [radio, setradio] = useState([])
  let dropdownvalue;

  useEffect(()=>{

    console.log(props.items);
    
  }, [])

  function dropDown(value) {
    dropdownvalue = value;
    console.log("Dropdown", dropdownvalue);
  }

  function onChangeValue(event) {
    console.log(radio);
  }

  function handleDelete() {
    console.log("Id-->", props.userid);
    const abortCont = new AbortController();
    console.log("Dropdown", dropdownvalue, radio);
    let data = {
      id: dropdownvalue,
      target: props.userid,
      radio: radio
    }

    fetch(`${configData.SERVER_URL}/admin/deleteuser`, {
      credentials: configData.COOKIES_CONFIG,
      signal: abortCont.signal,
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then(res => {
        if (!res.ok) {
          throw Error('Something Went Wrong')
        }
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(res_data => {
        if (res_data.status == false) {
          throw Error(res_data.message)
        } else {
          setPending(false);


        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        if (abortCont === "AbortError") {
        } else {
          setError(err.message);
          setPending(false);
        }

      })
  }

  function handleYes() {
    showConfirmDiv(false);
    showDeleteDiv(true);
  }

  return (

    <div>
      <Modal
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
        show={props.show}
        onHide={props.onHide}
      >

        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            Delete User
          </Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          {
            confirmDiv
            &&
            <>
              <h4>Do you really want to delete ??</h4>
            </>
          }
          {
            deleteDiv &&
            <div onChange={onChangeValue}>
              <p>Do you want to transfer user data to another user??</p>
              <input type="radio" value="Yes" name="Yes" onChange={() => showtransferDiv(true) || setradio(true)} />
              &nbsp;<label >Yes</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <input type="radio" value="No" name="Yes" onChange={() => showtransferDiv(false) || setradio(false) } />
              &nbsp;<label >No</label><br />
            </div>
          }
          {
            transferDiv &&
            <Form>

              <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                <Row>
                  <Col>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3">

                      
                    </Form.Group>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>

                    <Form.Select onChange={(e) => dropDown(e.target.value)}>
                      
                      <option value={props.items._id} >{props.items.name}</option>
                    </Form.Select>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Form.Group>
              <Form.Text className="text-muted">

              </Form.Text>
            </Form>

          }
          {
            pending && <p>Pending...</p>
          }
          {
            error && <p>{error}</p>
          }

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          {
            confirmDiv &&
            <>
              <Button onClick={handleYes}>Yes</Button>
              <Button onClick={props.onHide}>No</Button>
            </>
          }
          {
            deleteDiv &&
            <>
              <Button onClick={props.onHide}>Cancel</Button>
              <Button onClick={handleDelete}>Delete</Button>
            </>
          }
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TransferDialog;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you can try to replace

```
<option value={props.items._id} >{props.items.name}</option>
```

with this

```
{
props.items.map((element) => <option value={element._id} >{element.name}</option>)
}
```

You can also try this as it is better

```
{
renderOptions(props.items)
}
```

While renderOptions looks like this

```
function renderOptions(items) => items.map((item) => <option value={item._id} >{item.name}</option>)
```

Comment: props.items is giving me objects in return can't use map for object.

Comment: i have added image for prop.items to refer with.

Comment: Oooh I see, thanks for the image. How do you give props to TransferDialog and how do you render it?

Comment: What I am doing is    ` <td><Button onClick={() => setTransferDialog(true)} variant="outline-primary">Delete</Button>
                                            {transferDialog && <TransferDialog show={transferDialog} items={item} onHide={() => setTransferDialog(false)} ></TransferDialog>}</td> `

Comment: It looks like you've giving an item one by one to the component here: items={item}. What should return 'item'? That explain why you only have objects by objects, you might want to give all the items to the prop 'items'

Comment: Am i doing anythng wrong? i just needs to get all names in option Select list.

Comment: How to give all the items to the prop 'items'?

Comment: What is the value of 'item' in this part of code : `<td><Button onClick={() => setTransferDialog(true)} variant="outline-primary">Delete</Button> {transferDialog && <TransferDialog show={transferDialog} items={item} onHide={() => setTransferDialog(false)} ></TransferDialog>}</td>`

Comment: Array of Objects.

Comment: do you find any solution for this?

Comment: Not for the moment, if item is an array you should have no problems afterward

Answer (score 0):

Not getting clearly but your finding is to be iterate items on object entities. For that if we condition following aspects could solve the problem.
1 If props.items is array then you only need to use map above the  tag
2 If props.items is object then you can use forin loop to iterate and get the named fields and assigned in array state, then use map on the  tag.